# ¿Como poner links entre documentos en vim?

Tags: vim

Estoy haciendo una documentación personal en el editor VIM, tengo varios documentos y me gustaria poner un link que me lleve de un documento a otro, no se si exista alguna forma de poder hacerlo o algun pluggin para ayudarme a esta tarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si en cualquier documento de texto, tienes "escrito" un path relativo o absoluto a otro documento que eventualmente puedas abrir con Vim, por ejemplo en un documento tipo :

```
Mis trucos de programación -> prog-trucos.md
Otra información importante -> otros datos.md
```

Si tu cursor esta sobre el path, en modo "normal" puedes usar la combinación **`gf`** o `goto file`. En general Vim hace un buen trabajo para determinar el path a partir de la posición dónde estés, sin embargo, también puedes directamente seleccionar visualmente el path del texto.

Las particularidades de este comando las puedes ver [aquí](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor)

Por otro lado, si los enlaces apuntan a otro tipo de documentos, de los que necesitarás abrirlos con otra aplicación, tienes una forma similar a la anterior pero con las teclas **`gx`**